# Ubuntu 13.10 doesn't allow me to install "alongside" Windows, just "replace"

Tags: installation, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, windows-7

I have a disk with 3 partitions:

- 100MB for Windows 7
- 97.56GB for Windows 7
- 125.91 which I want to install Ubuntu on

How can I install Ubuntu on the 125.91 GB partition "alongside" Windows 7 (including grub etc) so I can dual boot between the two? Usually I get the "alongside" option available.

If I select "something else", click on the 125.91GB partition and then "install now" it says

"No root file system defined".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- After selecting `something else` , you would be presented with the 
  window which contains all your partition.
- Select the partition on which you want to install ubuntu (in your
  case it is 125.91 GB partition ).
- Now click on edit partition, It will present a popup window . Select
  "partition type" as `ext4 journaling file system`, check the "format
  partition" option and select "mount point" as `/`. Now click ok.
- It will ready the partition for ubuntu installation.  Now click on
  proceed button to proceed the  installation process.

Comment: Top man- exactly what I needed. Simple instructions!

Comment: Ok I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install Windows first, then install Ubuntu. The problem is that Windows will not prepare for you boot manager for two OS's alongside. Ubuntu is needed to be installed at the end.